# .show elements and .hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this problem :

- I have got 6 "outer" div's each have a img tag inside.
- Following each 6 div's are another div with content for each 6 divs

I want when i click one "outer" div hide all outer div's and show me the next div content.

This is the function. Wich it works there http://jsfiddle.net/Weinz/jdFRw/4/

But on test site only hide .outerDiv doesn't show next .innerDiv

```
$(function() {
    $(".outerDiv").click(function() {
        $(".outerDiv").hide();
        $(".innerDiv").hide();
        $(this).next("div").show();
    });
    $(".innerDiv").click(function() {
        $(".outerDiv").show();
        $(".innerDiv").hide();
    });
});
```

The real html code is this

```
<div class="block outerDiv"><a href="#"><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="165" height="74" alt="Temp" /></a></div>
     <div class="container innerDiv" style="display:none;">
```

I think the problem is on .next but i try diferent options and nothing work.

If i don't set the display in the innerDiv it works...

Comment: First thing I would check is that JQuery is loading?

Comment: It seems to work too with your final code http://jsfiddle.net/jdFRw/13/; is it similar to your code?

Comment: jQuery is loaded correctly. Yes is similar to this code.

http://alpha.venasanxenxo.com/trending/

This is the adress of the website. The divs are under #expositores section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
$(".outerDiv").click(function() {
    $(".outerDiv").hide();
    $(".innerDiv").hide();
    $(this).next("div").show().css('display', 'block');
});
$(".innerDiv").click(function() {
    $(".outerDiv").show();
    $(".innerDiv").hide();
});
```

});

Comment: Only hide the outerDiv's doesn't show the innerDiv.

 http://alpha.venasanxenxo.com/trending This is the adress of the website. The divs are under #expositores section